# add_theme_support not outputting thumbnails

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

so, i wanted to thumbnails in my query and i came across `add_theme_support`, it says you have to have that to enable actions such as `thumbnail`, so i put the following in my functions

```
function pippin_add_thumbnail_support() {
    if(!current_theme_supports('post-thumbnails')) {
        add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
    }
}
add_action('init', 'pippin_add_thumbnail_support');
```

Even after that code, my query doesn't generate a post thumbnail, when my query is

```
<?php
            $posts = get_posts(array('posts_per_page' => 4));
            foreach ($posts as $post) {
                if( has_post_thumbnail()){
                    get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail');

                echo $post->post_title;
                }
```

Am i missing something, or doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you put the 1st code in functions.php file? Also this may not directly work for the posts already added. You need to add/update the posts again to generate the required images or you can use regenerate thumbnails plugins to generate the images automatically.

Comment: @Chittaranjan yes do have it in my functions.php , but i think it was add/update the posts, as you mention. it worked.

Comment: Since the above tip worked for you, I have added that as an answer below and you can accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to echo the get_post_thumbnail in order for it to output.

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have images already added before adding the above piece of code, then you need to update the posts again to generate the required images. It will automatically work for all those posts which will be added from now.

If you have large number of images, then you can use [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to generate the images automatically.